# C# Draw text or line on axwindowsmediaplayer while video is being played

Tags: c#, text, graphics, line, axwindowsmediaplayer

I'm trying to overlay text/shapes on axwindowsmediaplayer in C#. I can draw line or text by creating graphics from axwindowsmediaplayer. but line/text disappears when video starts playing. Here is my code

```
Graphics g = axWindowsMediaPlayer.CreateGraphics();
g.DrawLine(new Point(10,10), new Point(20,20));
```

Comment: ok. i'm able to do it by snipping some code from 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20764/Overlay-Tools